# How can I print XPS without dialog?

Tags: c#, xps

I try to print to XPS printer (it's not my default printer), but the program opens me a dialog.
Can I skip the dialog? This is the code:

```
            pSettings = new PrinterSettings();                
            pSettings.PrintFileName = "test.xps";       
            RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pSettings.PrinterName, toSend);                
            spcn = new StandardPrintController();
            printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer";
            printDocument1.PrintController = spcn;                                    
            printDocument1.PrintPage +=
                new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
            printDocument1.Print();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print PDF to XPS without a dialog using Aspose API
[Aspose API](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Printing+PDF+to+an+XPS+File+and+Hiding+Print+Dialog+%28Facades%29)

```
//Create PdfViewer object and bind PDF file
PdfViewer pdfViewer = new PdfViewer();
pdfViewer.OpenPdfFile("input.pdf");

//Set PrinterSettings and PageSettings
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSetttings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
printerSetttings.Copies = 1;
printerSetttings.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer";

//Set output file name and PrintToFile attribute
printerSetttings.PrintFileName = "C:\\tempfiles\\printoutput.xps";
printerSetttings.PrintToFile = true;

**//Disable print page dialog**
**pdfViewer.PrintPageDialog = false;**

//Pass printer settings object to the method
pdfViewer.PrintDocumentWithSettings(printerSetttings);
pdfViewer.ClosePdfFile();
```

Comment: Thanks you, but whose PdfViewer DLL?  I have to add asambli refernce